# ffprobe: how do I get the time zone of creation date?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a video made with a canon camera (actually a PowerShow G5Xm2), I want to extract the creation date metadata, and I found that I can see it with:

```
$ ffprobe -i myfile.MP4 -show_entries stream_tags
[.....]
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'myfile.MP4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: mp42avc1CAEP
    make            : 
    make-eng        : 
    model           : 
    model-eng       : 
    creation_time   : 2022-08-28T15:25:09.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:53.96, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 29939 kb/s
  Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, bt709), 1920x1080, 29639 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25k tbn, 50k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2022-08-28T15:25:09.000000Z
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 253 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2022-08-28T15:25:09.000000Z
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
[STREAM]
TAG:creation_time=2022-08-28T15:25:09.000000Z
TAG:language=eng
TAG:vendor_id=[0][0][0][0]
[/STREAM]
[STREAM]
TAG:creation_time=2022-08-28T15:25:09.000000Z
TAG:language=eng
TAG:vendor_id=[0][0][0][0]
[/STREAM]
```

The creation date in in UTC, and it has the format "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ". The camera has the info of the time zone, and actually it converted the local time to UTC time, so I suppose that the MP4 should hide somewhere the time zone info.

How do I see it?

Comment: Check with exiftool to see if (a) EXIF data is available and if exists (b) if it has the timezone info. If data is available, it must be tucked away in other part of format/stream info. I vaguely recall looking for one before but cannot put my finger on it.

Comment: Apparently neither exiftool shows the TZ info...

Comment: Wait... exiftool has the ability to show date/times in local+tz format (like 2022:08:28 11:25:09-04:00) using the "-API QuickTimeUTC" flag. This means that tz info is in the mp4. But... how do I get with ffprobe?

Comment: That would be my guess. It must be there somewhere in the file... I'd dump all format & stream info onto a file (JSON maybe) and do a search for these keywords. There must be a field like `UserData` or `SideData` or something like that to hold those metadata...